# Name of a bean which is annotated with @Named without specifying any string in @Named?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, annotations

Suppose I have a bean which is injected using @Named annotation. For example,

```
@Named
public class MyBean {}
```

What will be the name of the bean during run time? I searched the net but couldn't find an answer. Also don't know how to debug to find the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the bean would be the class name.

Example : class CustomerService would be named customerService

Comment: Ok. I thought so but wanted to confirm.. So, would the above bean be named "MyBean" or "myBean" or "my-bean"?